# splitting text from a file between [ ] perl

Tags: perl, file, logging, split, substring

I am reading in from a log file and finding lines that have a certain error in them, after that I am able to output the line to a file.  But I don't want to output the whole line to the file, just the date that the error occurred.  The format of the log file is like this:
"[5/13/14 0:00:31:444 EDT] some other text".  I want to be able to just write the date to another file.  I am having trouble doing this with split.  Here is what I have:

```
if (/WSVR0605W/)
{
    my @vals =~ split(/\[/, $string);
    $vals[0] =~ s/\\//g;
    print ERRORFILE "$vals[0]\n";
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to split on `]` and later remove `[`.

```
    my @vals = split(/\]/, $string);
    $vals[0] =~ s/\[//;
```

which may be better job for regex,

```
my ($date) = $string =~ /\[(.+?)\]/;
```